# Remove Home element from navigation in Zend_Navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

Can I remove the Home element from the XML file containing menus.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configdata>
     <nav>
    <label>HOME</label>
    <controller>index</controller>
    <action>index</action>
    <id>root</id>
    <pages>...</pages>
....
```

When I delete it from the xml file (from line 4 to 7), I get an exception

> Zend_Navigation_Exception: Invalid argument: Unable to determine class to instantiate in C:\www\project\library\Zend\Navigation\Page.php on line 235

Answer (score 0):

Well , you remove lines related to Home element in addition to the <nav> tag !!!

and then XML file becomes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
<menu1>...</menu1>
<menu2>...</menu2>
...
</configdata>
```